# Reading exact text from the "Tj/TJ" operator of CGPDFDictionaryRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgpdfdictionaryref, cgpdfscanner

I am trying to read text from the **"Tj/TJ"** operator of CGPDFDictionary, but the TJ/Tj operator has the text in (encoded) format for e.g,
**Tj = <00><1F><05>**. Now i want to get this exact text in NSString i.e NSString should contain "<00><1F><05>".I tried to get the content from TJ/Tj in CGPDFStringRef, but when i am trying to    put it in **const unsigned char*** using **CGPDFStringGetBytePtr** or in **NSString** using **CGPDFStringCopyTextString** i am not getting the desired output. Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:

```
size_t length = CGPDFStringGetLength(string);
NSData *oprData = [NSData dataWithBytes:CGPDFStringGetBytePtr(string) length:length];
NSString *hexString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",oprData] uppercaseString];
```

Here **string** is the CGPDFStringRef. Finally we get the content of Tj/TJ operator in **hexString** variable.